# Generating constants ar compile time from file content

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's say I have a file with some constants in it. This file probably comes from a different service and might be different for different scenarios. Now I want to squeeze every last bit of performance out of my program, want the compiler to do as much optimization as possible and I would compile the project for every scenario separately if needed.

Is there a way to take a file at compile time, turn it into rust code through some conversion logic, e.g. generate some constants, and compile the result (all inside the rust tooling, no other code-generation)?

Comment: How you would do it largely depends on what those constants look like. Are they just numbers and arrays or such?

Comment: `const fn`s can't access files yet but they eventually might. If that is possible you could write `const MY_CONST: MyType = get_value_from_file();` + `const get_value_from_file() { ... }`

Comment: @Hadus As you wirte "can't access files _yet_". Is this part of Rust's agenda currently?

Comment: @TristanStorch: There have been [some chat](https://github.com/rust-lang/const-eval/issues/44) recently about this, but nothing definitive, AFAICT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you write a [`build.rs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) file in the root of your crate it will be compiled and run with each crate compilation.

It is usually used to build C bindings and such, but nothing prevents you from using it for your own purposes.

Usually this `build.rs` creates a Rust source file somewhere int the output directory, reading the `OUT_DIR` environment variable:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=data.txt");

    let out_dir = std::env::var_os("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let path = std::path::Path::new(&out_dir).join("test.rs");
    std::fs::write(&path, "pub fn test() { todo!() }").unwrap();
}
```

Then the source is included in your project, usually in its own module with:

```
mod test {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/test.rs"));
}
```

Comment: Even though there is code generation involved, this seems to be the best thing one can do for now. Not 100% happy, but, what can you do. Will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just generate rust source files that contain your constants.

These parts can be in any language:

1. Generate data you want to use as constants
2. Save them into rust source files as constants using some string manipulation

In rust:

1. `pub mod const_file` in `path/to/mod.rs`
2. `use path::to::const_file::MY_CONST;`
3. `cargo build` your rust program

Example for a constant array that you get from **python**:

```py
array = [0, 10, 34]
const_file_str = f"pub const MY_CONST: [u16; 3] = {array};\n"

with open("path/to/const_file.rs", "w") as rust_file:
    rust_file.write(const_file_str)
```

Comment: I had to do something like this to get over the const evaluation limit. (const initialisation cannot take forever)

Comment: As I wrote in my original question, I want to stay in the rust tooling realm and specifically avoid 'other code-generation'

Comment: The other answer is better but you could do the first two steps in the `build.rs` file.