Is it possible to compile with command-line arguments?
Is it possible to compile & execute Rust code where the compile step uses a command line parameter?
Example:
struct MyStruct {
  x: SmallVec<[usize; 120]>,
}

120 comes from choose(n, k); in this case for n=10, k=3.
What I want to do is something like (from the command line):

> compile_and_run mycode n k
a precompile step calculates choose(n, k) = n! / (k!(n-k)!)
mycode is compiled with the calculated value
mycode is executed.

It would be almost as good if it could just be compiled like this, and execution were a separate command.
To be clear, I already have code to calculate choose(n, k); I'm just asking whether it's possible to compile code based on something calculated off of command line parameters?
Is such a thing possible in Rust?
P.S., While the meat of my question has nothing to do with SmallVec, I'll include a link to the docs in case it's somehow relevant: https://docs.rs/smallvec/1.10.0/smallvec/struct.SmallVec.html

Someone downvoted this for lacking clarity. Is what I'm asking unclear? Please comment with any questions and I'll update to clarify.

I think this is the only option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340266/generating-constants-ar-compile-time-from-file-content

Same answer here with the only difference is getting the value from an environment variable rather than a file

You could use env! to read environment variables n and k during build, and then use a const function (if possible) or a proc macro to generate the number n choose k.

sounds like env! is the way to go here. If your precompilation step is complex enough, you might consider using the build.rs mechanism for it.

@kmdreko The linked question is about generating constants from file content, but I'm asking about generating constants from command line arguments. How does it answer my question?

I didn't vote to close your question if that's what you're assuming; I just commented that as a potential avenue.
